# trying google speech api but get an ImportError on client module

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-api, voice-recognition, google-cloud-sdk

I need to make a speech recognition (in french) for a project and I choose  the google speech api but I get the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python ~/sttG.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sttG.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import speech
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech.client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech/client.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.cloud.client import Client as BaseClient
ImportError: No module named client
```

first I install the google sdk and login with my account
then I install google cloud speech for python with this line:

```
$ pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech
```

And I got this error when I tried to launch this code:

```
from google.cloud import speech
client = speech.Client()
sample = client.sample(source_uri='gs://my-bucket/recording.flac',
                       encoding=speech.Encoding.FLAC,
                       sample_rate=44100)
results = sample.sync_recognize(
    language_code='en-GB', max_alternatives=2)
for result in results:
    for alternative in result.alternatives:
        print('=' * 20)
        print('transcript: ' + alternative.transcript)
        print('confidence: ' + str(alternative.confidence))
```

I follow these 2 pages:
[google-cloud-speech 0.25.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-speech#downloads)
[google-cloud client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/speech-usage.html#client)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the google-cloud client

```
sudo pip install google-cloud
```

That should do it

```
:~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Sep 17 2016, 20:26:04) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import speech
>>>
```